# Python Dask - dataframe.map_partitions() return value

Tags: python, pandas, dask

So `dask.dataframe.map_partitions()` takes a `func` argument and the `meta` kwarg. How exactly does it decide its return type? As an example:

Lots of csv's in ...\some_folder.

```
ddf = dd.read_csv(r"...\some_folder\*", usecols=['ColA', 'ColB'], 
                                        blocksize=None, 
                                        dtype={'ColA': np.float32, 'ColB': np.float32})
example_func = lambda x: x.iloc[-1] / len(x)
metaResult = pd.Series({'ColA': .1234, 'ColB': .1234})
result = ddf.map_partitions(example_func, meta=metaResult).compute()
```

I'm pretty new to "distributed" computing, but I would intuitively expect this to return a collection (a list or dict, most likely) of Series objects, yet the result is a Series object that could be considered a concatenation of the results of example_func on each partition. This in and of itself would also suffice, if this series had a MultiIndex to indicate the partition label.

From what I can tell from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39215617/what-is-map-partitions-doing), the [docs](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html), and [the source code itself](https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/dask/dataframe/core.py), this is because `ddf.divisions` will return a `(None, None, ..., None)` as a result of reading csv's? Is there a dask-native way to do this, or do I need to manually go in and break the returned Series (a concatenation of the Series that were returned by `example_func` on each partition) myself?

Also, feel free to correct my assumptions/practices here, as I'm new to dask.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> So dask.dataframe.map_partitions() takes a func argument and the meta
>   kwarg. How exactly does it decide its return type?

`map_partition` tries to concatenate the results returned by `func` to either a dask DataFrame or a dask Series object in an 'intelligent' way. This decision is based on the return value of `func`:

- If `func` returns a scalar, `map_partitions` returns a dask Series object.
- If `func` returns a pd.Series object, `map_partition` returns a dask Series object, in which all pd.Series objects returned by `func` are concatenated.
- If `func` returns a pd.DataFrame, map_partitions returns a dask Dataframe object, in which these pd.DataFrame obejcts are concatenated along the first axis.

If you are interested in the result of a special partition, you could use [`get_partition()`](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.get_partition). If the partition label is in general an important information for you, I would consider to assign a separate column of your ddf directly after reading in the data from csv, which contains all the information you need. Afterwards, you could construct `func` in a way, that it returns a pd.DataFrame containing the result of your calculation in one column and the information you need to identify the result in another.

Comment: An indicator column...duh! Accepted.

Comment: Ok, but how do you tell it to use a pandas.Series? It won't take the class. What is the symbol? It isn't in the docs.